# Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket - Can't login into Google Cloud Storage with ADC

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am following this tutorial to use Google Cloud Storage from my AppEngine application. Older storage libraries are working fine, but after migrating to Google Cloud Java Libraries, I can't read my buckets anymore.

This is the tutorial I am following: https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage

In which the key part is the usage of Application Default Credentials: https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage#creating-an-authorized-service-object

```
To make authenticated requests to Google Cloud Storage, you must create a service object with credentials. You can then make API calls by calling methods on the Storage service object. The simplest way to authenticate is to use Application Default Credentials. These credentials are automatically inferred from your environment, so you only need the following code to create your service object:

Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

I hope to be able to do this because this is running inside AppEngine, so Storage lives in the same project as the AppEngine code.

I am using the default service account. This service account has "owner" role in IAM configuration, and "storage object administrator" in the bucket itself.

[image]

[image]

However, I keep getting this login error:

com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException.translate(StorageException.java:118)
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:287)
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.get(HttpStorageRpc.java:479)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.lambda$get$4(StorageImpl.java:270)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.storage.Retrying.run(Retrying.java:54)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.run(StorageImpl.java:1406)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.get(StorageImpl.java:269)

[image]

Probably I am missing some configuration or IAM access. Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Anonymous caller** means your code is not using authorization (credentials). Your statement **I am using the default service account** is wrong.

Comment: Grant your Service Account the role Storage Admin. With the current role, you can only see the object, and you code ask for listing the bucket (you haven't that permission)

Comment: @JohnHanley you can see a picture that says "target service account: app engine default service account". The question is how to make it work properly. Can you add any value to your comment?

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere but as you can see, my service account has already this role: "administrador de objetos de storage" which is "storage object admin" in english

Comment: Anonymous caller means your code is not using authorization (credentials). It does not mean you do not have the correct permissions. It means you have zero permissions because the request does not include the HTTP **Authorization: Bearer** header.

Comment: I am pretending to use option 3 of authentication with Application Default Credentials (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java#application-default-cr), as this is running inside appengine in the same project that my storage account (and working with legacy storage services).

Also, this example also uses Application Default Credentials (without specifying any): https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage#creating-an-authorized-service-object

Comment: I do not know the solution to your problem as your question does not include enough code to reproduce your problem. I have made comments so that you understand what the error means. Understanding the problem is the first step to identifying the solution. Start over as your assumptions about using ADC is incorrect (a coding mistake, an environment problem, an incorrectly configured service, etc).

Comment: I am following the steps to use Application Default Credentials and liked all documentation of how should be used so the issue is not that my assumption is wrong. The issue is that following that steps I am getting an Anonymous user and not ADC with default service account.

Comment: @JavierDelgado, the `storage.buckets.get` permission  is not included in storage object admin role, only in storage admin.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquier, I have added the permission "storage.buckets.get" which I confused with "storage.objects.get" but I am still having the same issue. I think it has to do with tha authentication with ADC and not the permission itself

Comment: Is it app engine first or second generation?

Comment: App Engine Standard Environment Java 11, so I believe it is second generation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard I have recently updated to java 11 so I could work with java 8 too. I haven't introduced breaking changes yet.

Comment: I have declared GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and I am building my storage object with StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("project-id").build().getService() and the issue persists. Can I get the "caller" somehow to verify which service account is used ?